# When creating a native JSON array how to limit it to 10 most recent

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am creating a JSON array exactly as follows (bar using mathrandom).

For example purposes:

```
var numbers = [];
var jsonString = "";

function EveryOneSec() {
  numbers.push(Math.random());
  jsonString = JSON.stringify({'numbers': numbers});
  setTimeout(EveryOneSec, 1000);
}
```

When I create the JSON string it will obviously just keep getting bigger.

**Is there a way that I can only have the 10 most recently added into the array?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add the following code to the top of `EveryOneSec`

```
if (numbers.length == 10) {
    numbers.shift();
}
```

You want to use `push` and `shift` to ensure you always have the **recent** 10.

Comment: haha, I am just that fast ;) No, I wanted to upvote, but I had to wait until it was fixed!

Comment: @Ozaki. No problem. But the quickness goes to **Doug**

Answer (score 3):

There will be a few ways to handle this, but here is one (Comments added):

**Note** *I took the OP's question very literally. This lets the numbers array continue to grow, but limits the JSON version to only 10 items.*

```
var numbers = [];
var jsonString = "";

function EveryOneSec() {
  numbers.push(Math.random());
  // Get total number, minus 10 to get starting index
  var l = numbers.length - 10;

  // If l < 10 there are less than ten items, pass 0 to slice.
  // otherwise pass the starting index to get the last 10 numbers
  jsonString = JSON.stringify({'numbers': numbers.slice(l < 0 ? 0 : l)});
  setTimeout(EveryOneSec, 1000);
}
```

Comment: To me, this looks cleaner: `numbers.length > 10 ? numbers.slice(-10) : numbers`.

Comment: @Casey, that looks a lot cleaner... great suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

You could dispense with the problem of checking whether the size is ten or not by using

```
var number = Array(10);
```

Two downsides you would have to keep a running total of the index `i++` instead of using `numbers.push` and the JSON string would contain the blank spaces.  However, if I remember correctly `numbers[numbers.length] =` is supposed to be faster then `numbers.push()`.  So tracking your index might be faster.